# while read eliminates leading whitespace

Tags: bash, while-loop, whitespace

I try to print lines of a text which begin with a #
I need only these lines, but not the ones with [[:whitespace:]]#

```
$ cat text.txt
# no whitespace in front of #
   # 3 whitespace in front of #
  # tab in front of #
```

```
$ cat text.sh
#!/bin/bash
TEXT=text.txt
Sub=2     # required for the case-statement I have to perform in the real script

while read LINE ; do
  case $Sub:$LINE in
    2:"# "*)        printf "%s\n" "$LINE" ;;
  esac
done < "$TEXT"
```

```
$ ./text.sh
# no whitespace in front of #
# 3 whitespace in front of #     <<< the 3 whitespaces are gone
# tab in front of #              <<< the tab is also gone
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and the duplicate.

Comment: Many thanks Benjamin, it did not came to my mind that the IFS in combination with read is the cause of my problem. So I was continuously searching the wrong posts.